# Downloading multiple files

Tags: c#, download, backgroundworker

First of all, sorry for my English :(.

Hi, I've this code to download multiple files at once, but it's very glitchy when I'm downloading small files. If I lets say download a file that's 80 KB, then the label where I display the progress is spacing out :(.

This is the code I have right now:

```
bgwrkSplash.ReportProgress(44, 44444444444444);
ChangeText(lblStatus, "Downloading files to temp directory...", Color.Black);
DownloadFile();
resetEvent.WaitOne();

#region Download Handler

    private void DownloadFile()
    {
        if (_downloadUrls.Any())
        {
            _intCurrentProgressValue = prgSplashStatus.Value;
            _client.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;
            _client.DownloadFileCompleted += client_DownloadFileCompleted;

            var url = _downloadUrls.Dequeue();
            var uri = new Uri(url);
            _strFileName = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);

            _client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), _strTempLocation + _strFileName);
        }
    }

    private void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _byteCountFormatter.Add(new ByteCountFormatter {DataSize = e.BytesReceived, Time = DateTime.Now});
            _byteCountFormatter = _byteCountFormatter.Skip(Math.Min(0, _byteCountFormatter.Count - 6)).ToList();

            var speed = (_byteCountFormatter.Last().DataSize - _byteCountFormatter.First().DataSize)/
                        (_byteCountFormatter.Last().Time - _byteCountFormatter.First().Time).TotalSeconds;

            var timeRemaining = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((e.TotalBytesToReceive - e.BytesReceived)/speed);

            ChangeText(lblStatus, string.Format(
                "Downloading {0} - {1} - {2} of {3} ({4})",
                _strFileName,
                ByteCountFormatter.FormatTime(timeRemaining),
                ByteCountFormatter.FormatDataSize(e.BytesReceived),
                ByteCountFormatter.FormatDataSize(e.TotalBytesToReceive),
                ByteCountFormatter.FormatDataSpeed(speed)), Color.Black);
            ChangeProgress(prgSplashStatus, e.ProgressPercentage);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }
    }

    private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                {

                    throw e.Error;
                }
                if (e.Cancelled)
                {

                }
                DownloadFile();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }

            if (!_client.IsBusy)
            {
                ChangeProgress(prgSplashStatus, _intCurrentProgressValue);
                resetEvent.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Can you share or explain what exactly is the outcome, and what you're expecting out of your code?

Comment: I am expecting the code to like download multiple files from a queue. It does download them, but it looks really buggy :(.

Comment: By buggy, do you mean that the file order is changing?

Comment: Not really, the text that is displayed in the label is going crazy, it's displaying the text but the text gets all shuffled etc, I don't really know how to explain it :(.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or something?

Comment: @JKarthik I've added some picture how it looks like.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19402/discussion-between-jkarthik-and-foxyshadoww)

Comment: @FoxyShadoww Is ChangeText called from different threads? I think the text is jumbled up because multiple threads may be updating the progress (ChangeText). If true adding a lock inside ChangeText will make sure that text is not fuzzy.

Comment: Maybe you mean the label flickers??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed the Time Remaining part and it all goes smoothly now, thanks all!